# Forbidden error after moving up Yii site

Tags: php, yii, http-status-code-403

I had to move all my site up to its parent. Before the changes:

```
/
/yii
/new
    /css
    /js
    /img
    /protected
    /...
```

And after this change:

```
/
/yii
/css
/js
/img
/protected
/...
```

I changed the index.php file to point to the correct path of yii. However, it now shows this error when I call any controller:

> **Forbidden**
>
> You don't have permission to access /admin on this server.

Where /admin can be any controller or module within my site. My .htaccess, now on root too, is as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

# otherwise forward it to index.php
RewriteRule . index.php
```

It was working perfectly before I moved the site up. Has anybody faced this before? Thanks for taking your time.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some test here and everything worked fine for me.

Maybe you should try enable the logging to catch more info about this restriction. Also, you should check if your Apache directive `AllowOverride` if set to `All` for the root directory

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/blog/1.0/en/final.logging